# Aplicação não salva dados e só salva código

Tags: java, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um software para uma videolocadora com design pattern MVC (*Model-view-controller*) e está ocorrendo o problema de não salvar as pessoas.
Só salva o código das pessoas e nem sei o porque que está acontecendo de não salvar os clientes pois o meu código-fonte não apresenta erros!
No banco de dados MySQL as pessoas não estão com a opção assinalada `NOT NULL`.

Classe `VideoPessoa`, da camada *view*:

```
public class VideoPessoa extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    PessoaController pessoaController;
    Pessoa pessoa;




    /**
     * Creates new form Pessoa
     */
    public VideoPessoa() {
        initComponents();

        new Conexao();
        pessoaController = new PessoaController();
        pessoa = new Pessoa();
    }


private boolean salvarPessoa(){

     if (pessoaController.salvar(pessoa)) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Registro gravado com sucesso!");


    }else{

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro ao gravar os dados!", "ERRO", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }

    return true;


    }
```

Classe `PessoaController`:

```
  public class PessoaController {

    private final PessoaDAO pessoaDAO;


    public PessoaController() {
        pessoaDAO = new PessoaDAO();


    }

    public boolean salvar(Pessoa pessoa) {
  boolean retorno ;


    retorno = pessoaDAO.salvar(pessoa);


  return retorno;
}
```

Classe `PessoaDAO`, incluindo o método de salvar pessoas:

```
public class PessoaDAO {

    private Connection con;

    private final String SQLINSERT = " INSERT INTO pessoa(nome, endereco, bairro, sexo, telefone, celular, CPF, uf, cidade)"
            + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";

    private final String SQLPESSOAPELOCODIGO = "SELECT  nome, endereco, bairro, sexo, telefone, celular, CPF, uf, cidade"
            + " FROM pessoa"
            + " WHERE codigo=? ";

    private final String SQLSELECT = " SELECT  codigo, nome, endereco, bairro, sexo, telefone, celular, CPF,  uf, cidade FROM PESSOA";

    private final String SQLUPDATE = " UPDATE pessoa"
            + " SET nome = ?, "
            + " endereco = ?, "
            + " bairro   = ?, "
            + " sexo     = ?, "
            + " telefone = ?, "
            + " celular  = ?, "
            + " CPF      = ?, "

            + " uf       =?, "
            + " cidade   =?, "
            + " WHERE codigo = ?";
    private final String SQLDELETE = "DELETE FROM pessoa"
            + " WHERE codigo = ?";

    private PreparedStatement psInsert, sqlPessoaPeloCodigo, sqlSelect, sqlUpdate, sqlDelete;

    public PessoaDAO() {

        con = Conexao.getConnection();
        try {
            psInsert = con.prepareStatement(SQLINSERT);
            sqlPessoaPeloCodigo = con.prepareStatement(SQLPESSOAPELOCODIGO);
            sqlSelect = con.prepareStatement(SQLSELECT);
            sqlUpdate = con.prepareStatement(SQLUPDATE);
            sqlDelete = con.prepareStatement(SQLDELETE);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PessoaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }



public Pessoa getPessoaPeloCodigo(int codigo) {

        Pessoa pessoa = null;

        try {
            sqlPessoaPeloCodigo.setInt(1, codigo);
            ResultSet rs = sqlPessoaPeloCodigo.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                //Instancia o novo filme
                pessoa = new Pessoa();

                //Seta as informações no filme
                pessoa.setCodigo(rs.getInt("codigo"));
                pessoa.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                pessoa.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
                pessoa.setBairro(rs.getString("bairro"));
                pessoa.setSexo(rs.getString("sexo"));
                pessoa.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));
                pessoa.setCelular(rs.getString("celular"));
                pessoa.setCPF(rs.getString("CPF"));

                pessoa.setUf(rs.getString("uf"));
                pessoa.setCidade(rs.getString("cidade"));

            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PessoaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return pessoa;
    }

 public boolean salvar(Pessoa pessoa) {
        boolean retorno = false;

        try {
            psInsert.setString(1, pessoa.getNome());
            psInsert.setString(2, pessoa.getEndereco());
            psInsert.setString(3, pessoa.getBairro());
            psInsert.setString(4, pessoa.getSexo());
            psInsert.setString(5, pessoa.getTelefone());
            psInsert.setString(6, pessoa.getCelular());
            psInsert.setString(7, pessoa.getCPF());
            psInsert.setString(8, pessoa.getUf());
            psInsert.setString(9, pessoa.getCidade());

            psInsert.executeUpdate();
            retorno = true;

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PessoaDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

Classe `Conexao`:

```
public class Conexao {

    private static Connection con;

    public Conexao() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sistemavideolocadora2", "root", "1234");

            System.out.println(" Conexão obtida!!! ");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            System.out.println(" Conexão estabelecida com sucesso!!! ");
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return con;


    }

    public static void closeConnection() {
        try {
            con.close();

            System.out.println(" Conexão fechada!!! ");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            System.out.println(" Conexão finalizada com sucessso!!! ");
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dei uma refatorada no seu código. Sempre que possível, utilize a sintaxe *try-with-resources* com recursos que devem ser fechados adequadamente tais como `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` e `ResultSet`. Essa sintaxe garante que eles serão fechados de forma adequada com o mínimo de esforço de programação por parte do programador. Evite manter estes recursos abertos por tempo maior que o necessário a menos que você tenha uma razão muito forte para fazer isso (e no seu caso, não há nenhuma).

Também, a forma de notificar a ocorrência de um problema é com o lançamento de exceções. Não faça `return true;` se deu certo e `return false;` se deu um erro, pois a finalidade para a qual as exceções existem é exatamente para que você não precise fazer isso, então aprenda a usá-las. Além disso, a exceção pode transportar mais informações sobre o erro que não seriam possíveis somente com um simples `false`.

Também certifique-se de preencher todos os dados de `Pessoa` na view, tal como explicado por diversos colegas nos comentários na pergunta.

Desta forma, o seu código fica assim:

```java
/**
 * Classe que sinaliza a ocorrência de uma falha na persistência da aplicação.
 */
public class PersistenciaException extends Exception {

    /**
     * Construtor da exceção.
     * @param message A mensagem de erro.
     * @param cause A causa do erro.
     */
    public PersistenciaException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Conexao {

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    private Conexao() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Esta classe não deve ser instanciada.");
    }

    public static Connection openConnection() {
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sistemavideolocadora2", "root", "1234");
    }
}
```

```java
public class PessoaDAO {

    private final String SQLINSERT = " INSERT INTO pessoa(nome, endereco, bairro, sexo, telefone, celular, CPF, uf, cidade)"
            + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";

    private final String SQLPESSOAPELOCODIGO = "SELECT nome, endereco, bairro, sexo, telefone, celular, CPF, uf, cidade"
            + " FROM pessoa"
            + " WHERE codigo = ?";

    private final String SQLSELECT = "SELECT codigo, nome, endereco, bairro, sexo, telefone, celular, CPF, uf, cidade FROM PESSOA";

    private final String SQLUPDATE = "UPDATE pessoa"
            + " SET nome = ?,"
            + " endereco = ?,"
            + " bairro   = ?,"
            + " sexo     = ?,"
            + " telefone = ?,"
            + " celular  = ?,"
            + " CPF      = ?,"
            + " uf       = ?,"
            + " cidade   = ?,"
            + " WHERE codigo = ?";

    private final String SQLDELETE = "DELETE FROM pessoa"
            + " WHERE codigo = ?";

    public PessoaDAO() {
    }

    public Pessoa getPessoaPeloCodigo(int codigo) throws PersistenciaException {
        try (
            Connection con = Conexao.openConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SQLPESSOAPELOCODIGO)
        ) {
            ps.setInt(1, codigo);
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                if (!rs.next()) return null; // Não encontrou.
                // Instancia a nova pessoa.
                Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();

                // Seta as informações na pessoa
                pessoa.setCodigo(rs.getInt("codigo"));
                pessoa.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                pessoa.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
                pessoa.setBairro(rs.getString("bairro"));
                pessoa.setSexo(rs.getString("sexo"));
                pessoa.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));
                pessoa.setCelular(rs.getString("celular"));
                pessoa.setCPF(rs.getString("CPF"));
                pessoa.setUf(rs.getString("uf"));
                pessoa.setCidade(rs.getString("cidade"));
                return pessoa;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new PersistenciaException("Problema de SQL na consulta de pessoa por código.", ex);
        }
    }

    public void salvar(Pessoa pessoa) throws PersistenciaException {
        try (
            Connection con = Conexao.openConnection();
            PreparedStatement psInsert = con.prepareStatement(SQLINSERT)
        ) {
            psInsert.setString(1, pessoa.getNome());
            psInsert.setString(2, pessoa.getEndereco());
            psInsert.setString(3, pessoa.getBairro());
            psInsert.setString(4, pessoa.getSexo());
            psInsert.setString(5, pessoa.getTelefone());
            psInsert.setString(6, pessoa.getCelular());
            psInsert.setString(7, pessoa.getCPF());
            psInsert.setString(8, pessoa.getUf());
            psInsert.setString(9, pessoa.getCidade());

            psInsert.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new PersistenciaException("Problema de SQL na inserção de pessoa.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class PessoaController {
    private final PessoaDAO pessoaDAO;

    public PessoaController() {
        pessoaDAO = new PessoaDAO();
    }

    public void salvar(Pessoa pessoa) throws PersistenciaException {
        pessoaDAO.salvar(pessoa);
    }
}
```

```java
public class VideoPessoa extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private final PessoaController pessoaController;
    private Pessoa pessoa;

    /**
     * Creates new form Pessoa
     */
    public VideoPessoa() {
        initComponents();
        pessoaController = new PessoaController();
        pessoa = new Pessoa();
    }

    private void salvarPessoa() {
        try {
            pessoaController.salvar(pessoa);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Registro gravado com sucesso!");
        } catch (PersistenciaException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro ao gravar os dados!", "ERRO: " + ex.getMessage(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    // Resto da classe....
}
```

Comment: você me abriu os olhos e deu uma bela explicação para mim que muitos professores meus de faculdade não explicaram isso para mim durante minha faculdade.** Vou seguir seus conselhos e valeu cara! **

Comment: A palavra PersistenciaException  está dando erro e exibiu uma mensagenm que ela não tem javadoc e que tinha criar a classe para ela. Bem não sei como fazer isso.

Comment: @IgorContini Você não deveria ser obrigado a criar nenhum javadoc. Mas se por algum motivo você é obrigado a isso, atualizei a resposta com esse javadoc.

Comment: Beleza e valeu cara!

Comment: porque a classe não deve ser instanciada? Eu preciso que ela seja instanciada!

Comment: @IgorContini Esta pergunta é do ano passado, então não lembro direito o que você queria. Bem, a única classe que não é instanciável aqui é a `Conexao`, o motivo é porque uma instância dela não serviria para nada, uma vez que o único método desta classe que faz sentido ser chamado é estático. Entretanto, caso esta classe sofra algum tipo de alteração, ela pode vir a necessitar tornar-se instanciável.

Comment: Bem preciso que ela seja instanciada para meu DAO e quando rodo o meu sistema, dá esse erro: `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Esta classe não deve ser instanciada.")`

Comment: @IgorContini Essa exceção é lançada de dentro do construtor. Se você realmente precisa instanciar isso, é só apagar a linha do `throw` que está dentro do construtor. Entretanto, lembre-se que normalmente só faz sentido instanciar-se uma classe se você for usar os métodos de instância (não-estáticos) dela. A finalidade desta exceção é apenas não deixar você fazer uma operação sem sentido (instanciar uma classe para a qual a instância não serve para nada). Entretanto, se agora as instâncias fizerem sentido, essa exceção não seria mais necessário ou desejável e daí bastaria retirar o `throw`.

Comment: Apaguei a linha e causou outro erro: ` java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception util.PersistenciaException; must be caught or declared to be thrown `

Comment: @IgorContini Acho que você está usando o eclipse e fazendo hot-deploy. Recompile toda a aplicação e me diga qual é o erro de compilação e onde ele acontece.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43481/discussion-between-igor-contini-and-victor-stafusa).

Answer (score 3):

Você não setou valores no objeto pessoa, pelo menos não achei o métodos sets no código:

```
    public VideoPessoa() {
        initComponents();

        new Conexao();
        pessoaController = new PessoaController();
        pessoa = new Pessoa();
    }


    private boolean salvarPessoa(){

     if (pessoaController.salvar(pessoa)) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Registro gravado com sucesso!");
ETC...
```

Portanto passa pessoaController.salvar(vazio), o correto seria:

```
    public VideoPessoa() {
        initComponents();

        new Conexao();
        pessoaController = new PessoaController();
        pessoa = new Pessoa();
        pessoa.setnome('alguem');
        pessoa.settelefone('(11) 999991111');
    }


    private boolean salvarPessoa(){

     if (pessoaController.salvar(pessoa)) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Registro gravado com sucesso!");
ETC...
```

Não sei se a syntax ta certa, qualquer erro na reposta favor informar, obrigado.

Comment: Creio que esse seja um dos problemas, como ele mesmo disse quando ele coloca um `sysout` no método salvarPessoa() isso é exibido: Pessoa: Pessoa{nome=null, endereco=null, bairro=null, sexo=null, telefone=null, celular=null, CPF=null, codigo=0, cidade=null, uf=null, pessoa=null} `

Comment: @Techies, Deve ser e só não retorna erro por que deve ser tudo not null e chave primária auto incremental no banco de dados.

Comment: Sim eu pensei nisso também, mas o código dele está muito "bagunçado" não consegui entender direito

Comment: @TiagoOliveiradeFreitas isso mesmo, mas os atributos da pessoa está com a opção [tag:null] assinalada.

Comment: @Techies dá desconto que sou iniciante ainda!

Comment: @TiagoOliveiradeFreitas Era o que estava faltando para salvar os atributos da minha pessoa e eu não sabia que precisa setar eles antes da minha inserção.Valeu cara pela resposta!